# vuetify: v-checkbox with image as label

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm trying to creaet a v-checkbox with an image as a label. I've got the problem that I can't give the image a specific size (width) so that it stays in the given v-col space. The image is always a lot wider than the given v-col space.

It didn't worked with #append in the template too.

Here is the code:

```
    <v-col
      xs="12"
      lg="3"
    >
      <v-checkbox
        v-model="selectedItem"
        :value="item.id"
      >
        <template #label>
          <v-img
            :src="item.logo"
            style="width: 100%"
          />
        </template>
      </v-checkbox>
    </v-col>
```

My goal is it to have a row with several cols. in the first one should be a checkbox with an image instead of a label. The checkbox and the image should be next to each other in one line and the image shouldn't be wider than the col.

Maybe someone has an idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `v-avatar` inside of the label slot to control the image size. check the demo below:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    checkbox: false,
    imageSize: 50,
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-slider v-model="imageSize" label="image size" min="25" max="128" style="width: 200px"></v-slider>
        <v-checkbox v-model="checkbox">
          <template v-slot:label>
            <v-avatar tile :size="imageSize">
              <img
                src="https://picsum.photos/id/1025/200"
              > 
            </v-avatar>
          </template>
        </v-checkbox>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I've searched - thank you!! :D